# sql declare variable string and use in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
replace(replace(Names,'Lara',''),'M','')
```

is working, but

```
declare @midname varchar
set @midname = 'Lara'
replace(replace(Names,@midname,''),'M','')
```

is not working

Comment: you have not define the size of @mindname

Comment: You don't need to define the size. Gopi, can you tell us what error it's throwing? Your syntax is correct, it should work.

Comment: @MichaelCapobianco: without the size, it's varchar(1).

Comment: @JohnSaunders You're right, my mistake ^^

Comment: `declare @midname varchar` declares a variable of **1 character length** - is that really what you're looking for?? **ALWAYS** explicitly define your desired length - something like `declare @midname varchar(100)` or whatever fits your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put your code in a code box. It is hard to be sure what you have but this should work.

```
DECLARE @midname varchar(200); 
SET @midname = 'Lara'; 
SELECT Replace(Replace(Names,@midname,''),'M','');
```

Names looks like it should be a variable, not sure about how you are using it.

Comment: You need the SELECT before replace and a varchar scale e.g `declare @midname varchar(200)`

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable as `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: I disagree with max in this case and he didn't want unicode.

Comment: @RussellHart - `NVARCHAR` is a matter of habit.  It is only a matter of time before some of the natural language data will contain it.  There is a good reason why procedural languages of the Java generation do not give you a real choice between a 7bit character set and Unicode.

Comment: I usually declare as nvarchar too. However, if you know you do not need unicode and it is a very large dataset then switching to varchar will half the storage size (also good for IO).
I also can't recall seeing a person's name using unicode characters but I may be wrong. 
And just to clarify it is an 8-bit set in this case.

Comment: @RusellHart - my own first name has 4 characters, but only 2 of those occur in ASCII, which is a widely used 7 bit character set.  The 8th bit does not really solve the problem if you need a different 8 bit encoding for each person's name.  Sad is the software product that needs a full rewrite upon going global.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this as an update statement if you want the data to update

```
declare @midname varchar(200)
set @midname = 'Lara'


update [table_name]
set Names =  replace(replace(Names,@midname,''),'M','')
```